# Automated Normalization?

Tags: normalization, automatic-algorithms

The most widely used statistical techniques assume a normal distribution for inputs.  The most widely used normalization procedures take a:

1. square root (assuming polynomial distribution),
2. log (assuming exponential distribution), or
3. ratio (assuming the denominator scales the numerator, eg per
   capita)

Give a large number of variables, without any prior knowledge of them, are there techniques to automate the choice of these techniques to maximize their compliance with the normal distribution assumption?

Comment: Normality is only (normally) required for the errors from a useful model to construct parametric tests of necessity and sufficiency. Outlier detection can often be used to isolate unusual values.

Comment: Did you look into Box-Cox transform?

Comment: That may prove useful.  I wonder if one can get away with avoiding taking ratios and just correlate the Box-Cox transformed counts.

Comment: One cannot "get away with avoiding taking ratios".  If, for example, by-State measures had Rhode Island (pop 1M) with 5 times the murders per capita of California (pop 40M), the ratio exposes critical information whereas Box-Cox hides it by placing RI more in the center (median, mean, whatever) of the count of murders.